# SQLServer Linux: Error restoring backup of DB from Windows w/ full-text data file

Tags: sql-server, restore, linux, sql-server-2017, catalogs

I'm trying to move a Windows SQL Server database from Windows 10 to Linux.

For this, I'm following the instructions in

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-restore-database?view=sql-server-linux-2017

The linux database is freshly installed in an Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

The Windows database backup is a previously existing (I have not executed the backup, but it's a full backup)

When I try to restore, it generates an error in the catalog database (access denied), as shown (database name changed to 'mydb' for privacy):

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "RESTORE DATABASE mydb 
FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/mydb_backup_201804300000.bak' 
WITH MOVE 'mydb' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/mydb.mdf', 
MOVE 'mydb_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/mydb_log.ldf', 
MOVE 'sysft_appuser_catalog3' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/catalog.ft'"

Msg 7610, Level 16, State 1, Server irulan, Line 1
Acceso denegado a '/var/opt/mssql/data/catalog.ft' o la ruta de acceso no es válida.
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 50, Server irulan, Line 1
El archivo 'sysft_appuser_catalog3' no se puede restaurar en '/var/opt/mssql/data/catalog.ft'. Utilice WITH MOVE para identificar una ubicación válida para el archivo.
```

The other 2 files (mdf and ldf) are created without problems in the same folder). I have tried with different file names, creating previously (touch) the file, and so on with no success.

How can I restore this database?

I'd be willing to restore it without the full-text index - is there a way to do that?

This is the output of FILELISTONLY (to check the content of backup)

```
LogicalName                                                                                                                      PhysicalName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Type FileGroupName                                                                                                                    Size                 MaxSize              FileId               CreateLSN                   DropLSN                     UniqueId                             ReadOnlyLSN                 ReadWriteLSN                BackupSizeInBytes    SourceBlockSize FileGroupId LogGroupGUID                         DifferentialBaseLSN         DifferentialBaseGUID                 IsReadOnly IsPresent TDEThumbprint                              SnapshotUrl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------------- --------------------------- ------------------------------------ --------------------------- --------------------------- -------------------- --------------- ----------- ------------------------------------ --------------------------- ------------------------------------ ---------- --------- ------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mydb                                                                                                                             D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\mydb.mdf                                                                                                                                                                                                    D    PRIMARY                                                                                                                                    3460300800       35184372080640                    1                           0                           0 D64B0490-3FF6-4EFE-A9A1-491B5993F3AF                           0                           0           2348613632             512           1 NULL                                        30094000017824000037 B7E468AB-78C2-4732-8D73-2F07E3ABAF9D          0         1 NULL                                       NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
mydb_log                                                                                                                         D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\mydb_log.ldf                                                                                                                                                                                                L    NULL                                                                                                                                       1540227072        2199023255552                    2                           0                           0 A6B8CF28-C3D8-4B50-B030-4D5B14F82084                           0                           0                    0             512           0 NULL                                                           0 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000          0         1 NULL                                       NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
sysft_appuser_catalog3                                                                                                           D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\FTData\appuser_catalog3                                                                                                                                                                                          F    PRIMARY                                                                                                                                        931744                    0                65539        17974000000690900001                           0 0B0AEAB0-86A2-42ED-9B37-E70EE556383C                           0                           0               983040             512           1 NULL                                        30094000017824000037 B7E468AB-78C2-4732-8D73-2F07E3ABAF9D          0         1 NULL                                       NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

(3 rows affected)
```

Note: I have found this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536182/mssql2005-restore-database-without-restoring-full-text-catalog); the poster had a different problem, but was also willing to restore the DB without the full-text data. It doesn't say how (if!) he ever resolved his problem, so it doesn't really give me an answer.

Comment: The Stack Overflow post you provide a link to isn't the same problem - that individual was trying to restore the DB, including the full-text index, and had indicated that the data and log files should be moved, but not that the full-text file should be moved; the error was that they couldn't write the full-text file because there was already a file with the same name, and it was in use (by the original copy of the database).

Comment: Thanks! I know it is not the same problem, but, is it posible to restore a full database without text. If yes, the solution will be enough for me.

Comment: Not that I know of - if the .ft file is a part of the backup, then it has to go somewhere. Have you tried changing the directory the .ft file is written to?

Comment: Are you sure that the `restore` was able to restore the other two files successfully - did the error not happen until after those files were created? Can you get another Windows backup of a DB *without* a full-text index, and try to restore that?

Comment: Thanks for the editing! Yes, I have tried 2 different folders. Originally I tested in personal folder (for the 3 files, mdf, ldf and ft). After, I tried in the mssql/data folder as suggested by MS docs. And, yes, I changed in both cases `chmod 777 data``

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, it there is a previous try, the mdf and ldf files existed (and the error message was different - file is use). So, in any test now I clean the directory.

Comment: Is FTS installed on Ubuntu? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-full-text-search

Comment: Thanks, @RandolphWest!! I had not installed the FTS. I have installed following the MS document, but no change in the error (after restarting the service, as requested by fts installation)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and found a workaround by specifying a combination of Windows/Linux path for the full text files in the restore database files as options.  E.g. instead of the configured default "/SQLServerData/catalogname", I changed it to "C:\SQLServerData/catalogname" and then it was happy.